# How  to make  the  Default focus   in  content page from master page 

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, master-pages

I have  masterpage   with   content place  holder. i have    contentpage  which is   using master page  . in all  my  content  page i need  to   default focus  on the text box  so  that  the user  can  directly  type in text box   instead  moving the   mouse  over the textbox. in   some  page there is   no text  box so that i  donnot nnet  keep      default   focus  over  there

Is there  any  way i  can   do it  in my master page  once  and  can  reuse    that in  all my  content page

thank  you

Answer (score 3):

try using this...

```
((TextBox)Master.FindControl("txtRequiredFocus")).Focus();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could include this in your master page's load event:

```
// if the ID is constant you can use this:
/*TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Page.Controls[0]
                                .FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1")
                                .FindControl("myTextBox");
*/

// this will look for the 1st textbox without hardcoding the ID
TextBox textBox = (TextBox)Page.Controls[0]
                            .FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1")
                            .Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                            .FirstOrDefault();

if (textBox != null)
{
    textBox.Focus();
}
```

This would match up with a content page that has the following markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

**EDIT:** if LINQ isn't an option then you can use this instead:

```
foreach (Control control in Page.Controls[0].FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1").Controls)
{
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        ((TextBox)control).Focus();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: but in  page   the  ID  of the  textbox  control is   diffrent page1:  as txtusername
page2: as  txtemployeeid

Comment: so i cannot  tell  in javscript  use this  control  as  default  focus  on all the page

Comment: @prince23: I've updated the code so that the ID no longer matters. @David Andres and @Nathan Taylor have posted Javascript approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Indiscriminate JavaScript approach to selecting the first valid input field on a page:

```
function SelectFirstInput() {
    var bFound = false;
    for (f = 0; f < document.forms.length; f++) {
        // for each element in each form
        for (i = 0; i < document.forms[f].length; i++) {
            // if it's not a hidden element
            if (document.forms[f][i].type != "hidden") {
                // and it's not disabled
                if (document.forms[f][i].disabled != true) {
                    // set the focus to it
                    document.forms[f][i].focus();
                    var bFound = true;
                }
            }
            // if found in this element, stop looking
            if (bFound == true)
                break;
        }
        // if found in this form, stop looking
        if (bFound == true)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah... It's ugly... but it works well in all the browsers. A client asked for this feature recently and I didn't want to add jquery to their whole site- so I found this snippet for them :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >


window.onload=function(){
var t= document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.clientID %>');
t.focus();
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, a possible solution is:

1. Give the textbox you want to set focus to a special class.  "focus" works well for this purpose.
2. Write code such as the following in your master page or included by your master page in a js script file:

   ```
   $(document).ready    
   (

     function()
     {
       //get an array of DOM elements matching the input.focus selector
       var focusElements = $("input.focus").get();

       //if a focus element exists
       if(focusElements.length > 0)
       {
         focusElements[0].focus();
       }
     }
   );
   ```

A similar approach using vanilla JavaScript would be to tag the textbox with a special attribute.  Let's use focus.

```
window.onload = function()
{
  //get all input elements
  var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

  var elementToFocus = null;

  for(var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; ++i) 
  {
    var focusAttribute = inputElements[i].getAttribute("focus");

    if(focusAttribute)
    {
      elementToFocus = inputElements[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  if(elementToFocus)
  {
    elementToFocus.focus();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Control masterC = 
Page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
    TextBox TextBox1 = 
masterC.FindControl("TextBoxUsername") as TextBox;

TextBox1.Focus();
```