# asp.net textbox focus problems

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to set focus on textbox on page load in asp.net as follows

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               // fillUnitType();
                //
                fillLastCode();
                txt_Grn_Date.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                setinitialrow_lvl();
 txt_Po_No.Focus();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

But the textbox is not getting focused. What is that I am missing. I have used update panel is it because of that.? Or my css is slightly faulty.

Comment: too little information

Comment: Past the code txt_Po_No.Focus(); in out side of! isPostBack

Comment: @RameshRajendran : not working.

Comment: try ramesh's suggestion

Comment: It's due to update panel just place your textbox outside the update panel & see.

Comment: Try : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1403523/1136253

Answer (score 1):

try this in javascript

```
<script language=javascript>

function fnLoad(){
document.getElementById("<%= txt_Po_No.ClientID %>").focus();

}

</script>
```

call "`fnLoad`()" function on "`onLoad`" event of body..

You need to add this function in body tag : Like

```
<body onload="fnLoad()">........</body>
```

**Update:**

try another way

```
<script language=javascript>
    $(document).ready(function(){  document.getElementById("<%= txt_Po_No.ClientID %>").focus();}) 
  </script>
```

or

```
<script language=javascript>
        $(window).load(function(){  document.getElementById("<%= txt_Po_No.ClientID %>").focus();}) 
      </script>
```

Comment: absolutely . But must call the function in body tag .

Comment: When I use ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(),"id","callMyJSFunction()",true); this my controls disappera. Page gets blank.

Comment: You need to add this function in body tag : Like '<body onload="fnLoad()"></body>'

Comment: I have a master page. So there is no body tag.

Answer (score 1):

Write following function in your codebehind and for every control call this function

```
private void Set_Focus(string controlname)
{
string strScript;

strScript = "<script language=javascript> document.all('" + controlname + "').focus() </script>";
RegisterStartupScript("focus", strScript);
}
```

Set

```
tapindex = 0
TextBox1.Focus();
```

or

```
 textBox1.Select();
```

or

```
 protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Focus();
        base.OnShown(e);
    }
```

or

```
setTimeout("myFocusFunction()", 500);

    function myFocusFunction(){
        $("#myTextBoxID").focus();
    }
```

Comment: Its working.Paste this function in code behind.From pageload call this function with Set_Focus(textbox1.text) as parameter..

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this with updatepanel and textbox inside it.

**CodeBehind**

[image: CodeBehind]

**.aspx**

[image: .aspx]

**output**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
string jsCode= "<script language=javascript>document.getElementById('<%= TEXTBOX.ClientID%>').focus();</script>";   


ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "txtbox",jsCode, false);
```